# How to fix the collapse/expand shortcuts in Progress Developer Studio?

Tags: ide, progress-4gl, openedge

I like to collapse procedures and functions to one liners. I can use the existing [-] or [+] button next to the collapsable/expandable things in the editor to trigger it. But this is not usable for procedure files containing like 10 functions, as it takes too long to click them thru.

However, any of the shortcuts set in the `Keys` section of Eclipse's `Preferences` don't work. By running a command by it's name, f.ex `Collapse All` or `Expand All` the IDE does nothing.

I think this is because the `Progress` hasn't wired these functions correctly or at all. I'm currently using the Eclipse Version: 4.3.2 (KEPLER) with `Progress` Version: 11.6.2.00.

Is there any way to create/enable these shortcuts for these actions?

Comment: I would log that as a bug with Progress. It's not working in 11.7 either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually expected behavior according to Progress.

**Question/Problem Description**

> Ctrl+Numpad-Multiply does not expand all sections in Progress Developer Studio for Open Edge or OpenEdge Architect editor.
>
> The General>Keys preference in Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge / OpenEdge Architect lists an Expand All command bound to the Ctrl+Num-Multiply key combination, but this key combo does not have any effect.

**Cause**

> This is expected behavior. The Expand All command has not been implemented in OpenEdge Architect or Progress Developer Studio.

As a note I think this is on the verge of a bug but at least a quite clear case where an improvement can be done. I will add it to the Ideas forum at community.progress.com as a feature request.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000045062

Comment: Thanks for you and Mike!